# Excel macro that saves all open workbooks if they meet certain criteria

Tags: vba, excel, macros

How do I write a macro that runs through open workbooks and saves them with a specific name depending on the contents of each workbook. Each workbook have unique column headings in worksheet "Book1" so the workbook can be determined by the text in cell A1. If workbook and worksheet Book1 and cell A1 = "Currency" save active workbook as Y:\risk\CCY.csv if cell A1 = "Interest" save active workbook as Y:\risk\IR.csv. Loop through all open workbooks until no open workbooks meets the criteria.

Comment: Have you tried to write a macro to do this, or have you even tried to record a macro (as you complete the task) to see what Excel is doing?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any experience with VBA? I used the macro recorder to figure out how to save. I made the following code and tested it, it worked fine for me. I did try running it twice and it prompted me if I wanted to overwrite the file. There is no other error handling built in it though.

```
Sub SaveWorkbooks()

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim FileName As String, FolderPath As String
Dim SaveWorkbook As Boolean

FolderPath = "Y:\risk"
ChDir FolderPath

For Each WB In Workbooks
    Select Case WB.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Value
        Case Is = "Currency"
            FileName = "CCY"
        Case Is = "Interest"
            FileName = "IR"
        Case Else
            FileName = ""
    End Select
    'Make sure it's not saving not applicable workbooks
    If FileName <> "" Then SaveWorkbook = True Else SaveWorkbook = False

    If SaveWorkbook = True Then
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FolderPath & "\" & FileName & ".xlsx", _
            FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    End If

Next WB

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for spending time on this and thank you for the suggested code. These forums are new to me and obviously I have misunderstood something. It is interesting though that you are met with not so welcoming remarks. I have little VBA experience but years (decades) of excel functions and standard macro recording. I didn't get the code to work a 100% but I will work on it and see if I can solve it. It finds one "Case" and saves that in two different names.

Comment: No problem. If you found the answer to be the best solution, make sure you go ahead and mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 1):

I agree, with @thecoshman this hurt my eyes to read. This one time I'll make an exception. Try this:

```
Sub SaveWorkbooks()
Dim workbookObj As Workbook

For Each workbookObj In Excel.Workbooks
    If workbookObj.Sheets("Book1").Range("A1").Value = "whatever" Then
        workbookObj.Save
        workbookObj.Close
    End If
Next workbookObj

'Clean up
Set workbookObj = Nothing
End Sub
```